# NHibernate query to get objects with properties that match string parts

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a `Person` class with the following properties:

```
public class Person
{
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string FirstName{ get; set; }
  public string SecondName { get; set; }
  public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

The user is presented with a search box where they can enter a string separated with spaces. The task is to query from the DB all the Persons that have any property equal to any part of the entered string (the parts are substrings split by spaces). The simplest solution is to OR all possible combinations. But, in my sense, it doesn't seem right. Are there more elegant solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried the solution I've mentioned above. I've ORed all the combinations of each property and substring.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried?  It seems you would only want to OR the combinations together that have been entered using a list of restrictions filtering on fields.

Comment: Yes, I do `OR` my properties and parts of the entered string now. Something like that: `foreach (var s in substrings) foreach (var p in properties) criterion = Restrictions.Or(criterion, Restrictions.InsensitiveLike(p, string.Format("%{0}%", s)));` And based on the given answer I'm going to stick with this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer begins with the definition of  `What does elegant mean?`

There are solutions such as:-

1. Create a computed column on the database [FirstName] + N' ' + [Surname] + N' ' + [SecondName] etc.  Then you only need to `OR` the substrings based on the computed column - Is this elegant/more performant? I for one am not so sure.
2. Create a `FREETEXTABLE` See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx) for more info. Again you only need to `OR` against each substring (based on SQL server FULL-TEXT sarch).
3. Implement a LUCENE index on all the columns, see [this](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/). However syncing problems with the database needs to be thought about and also you will need to learn a new framework BUT searching is definitely IMO more elegant.
4. Stay with what you got.

Which you decide is up to you but 1-3 have different issues against something that you currently have, which my not be elegant, but it is simple and most likely works!

Comment: It seems I'm overcomplicating the matter. I'll use what I already use. Thanks!